# Remove duplicated rows in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to remove duplicated rows in sql. My table looks like that:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table 
(
id Serial,
Date Date,
Time Time,
Open double precision, 
High double precision, 
Low double precision
);


DELETE FROM test_table
WHERE ctid IN (SELECT min(ctid)
    FROM test_table
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING count(*) > 1);
```

with the below `delete` statement I am searching in the secret column `ctid` for duplicated entries and delete them. However this does not work correctly. The query gets executed properly, but does not delete anything.

I appreciate your answer!

**UPDATE**

This is some sample data(without the generated `id`):

```
2013.11.07,12:43,1.35162,1.35162,1.35143,1.35144
2013.11.07,12:43,1.35162,1.35162,1.35143,1.35144
2013.11.07,12:44,1.35144,1.35144,1.35141,1.35142
2013.11.07,12:45,1.35143,1.35152,1.35143,1.35151
2013.11.07,12:46,1.35151,1.35152,1.35149,1.35152
```

Comment: Note this method you're using would only delete one of each duplicate, you'd need to keep running it until affected rows==0;

Comment: @user2051347 can you show some sample data

Comment: @Mihai have a look at the update!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get out of the habit of using `ctid`, `xid`, etc. - they're not advertised for a reason.

One way of dealing with duplicate rows in one shot, depending on how recent your postgres version is:

```
with unique_rows
as
(
  select distinct on (id) *
  from test_table
),
delete_rows
as
(
  delete
  from test_table
)
insert into test_table
select *
from unique_rows
;
```

Or break everything up in three steps and use temp tables:

```
create temp table unique_rows
as
select distinct on (id) *
from test_table
;

create temp table delete_rows
as
delete
from test_table
;

insert into test_table
select *
from unique_rows
;
```

Comment: Thx for your answer! However using your query I am getting a syntax error at: `...as
delete
from test_table
;`

Comment: btw I tried it again with your first query and basically you are only checking for duplicated id`s. However this does not check the whole ros. Is this correct?

Comment: The syntax error means you're using a slightly older version of postgres. Just use the second set of queries then. And yes - the check is only for duplicates on the id's.

Comment: Can I also check for the distinctness of the whole row?

Comment: I edited your query by(the `select distinct part`): `  select distinct on (id, date, time, open, high, low, close, volume) *
  from test_table` However this does not give me the distinct row back... Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Which actually distinguishes the rows? I'm guessing the date and time? In that case you want "distinct on (date, time)".

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can use row_number with partiontions in postgresql but if so you can do this to find duplicates, you can add or substract columns from the partion by to define what duplicates are in the set

```
WITH cte AS
(
SELECT id,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Date, Time ORDER BY date, time) AS rown 
FROM test_table
)
delete From test_table
where id in (select id from cte where rown > 1);
```

Comment: Thx for your answer! However when using your query I am getting an error with `cte`: `Relation »cte« does not exist.`